# Script that deletes any duplicate line and keeps the original order

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

Need to write a script that will process standard input and remove each duplicated line found till the end of the standard input. Each copy but also the first option of a linear duplicate will be deleted, regardless of whether there is the other one or scattered in the entry. The standard output displays only the lines (in the received order of entry) which had no duplicate entry.
For exemple we have the file `test.txt` containing the following :

```
Whatever
You
Want
You
To
Whatever
Have
Here
```

Output is supposed to have all the duplicated lines deleted and the order of the lines the same as input like this :

```
Want
To
Have
Here
```

Note that we don't know what the file contains (this is just an example). I tested out many commands but couldn't find one that works and respects the requirements.

`IMPORTANT NOTE : I need all occurences of the line to be deleted`,

```
  not only all of them after the first one
```

Comment: Your example input contains lines differing by number of spaces (for example: `You  ` and `You   `). Why does the output treat them as being the same?

Comment: For first occurrence of **identical** lines in "small" input: `| awk '!seen[$0]++'`

Comment: For **large** input: `| cat -n | sort -k2 | uniq -f1 | sort -n -k1,1 | sed '^[ 0-9]*\t//'`

Comment: For **huge** (neverending?) input: store lines in a database and perform lookup

Comment: What code you need also depends on whether your input contains a small number of strings repeated a few times (eg. `yes | head -n 100000000 |`) or a large number of strings repeated seldom (eg. `yes | cat -n | head -n 100000000 |`)

Comment: Apologies for the extra spaces, i just gave an example. Ofc if they have extra spaces they shouldn't treat the lines the same

Comment: the sed command doesn't work, also those solutions i saw on the internet aswell but don't do what i actually need to

Comment: the sed command got mangled when I typed it in: `| cat -n | sort -k2 -s | uniq -f1 | sort -n -k1,1 | sed 's/^[ 0-9]*\t//'`

Comment: with GNU sed, it's probably faster as: `| cat -n | sort -k2 -s -u | sort -n -k1,1 | sed 's/^[ 0-9]*\t//'` (and I've added `-s` option to sort to ensure the first line is retained)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what 'Each copy but also the first option of a linear duplicate will be deleted' means, but I think you are just looking for:

```
awk '!a[$0]++'
```

or perhaps:

```
awk '!a[$1]++'
```

eg:

```
$ cat input
Whatever
You
Want
Whatever 1
You
To
Whatever 1
Have
Here
$ awk '!a[$0]++' input
Whatever
You
Want
Whatever 1
To
Have
Here
$ awk '!a[$1]++' input
Whatever
You
Want
To
Have
Here
```

Comment: I need to have all duplicated lines deleted

Comment: @JonBjatBun I don't understand your comment.  The first solution removes all duplicated lines. The second solution deletes all lines in which only the first column is duplicated.